# ubercart recurring payment for paypal

Tags: ubercart

Does any one have experience of implementing uc_recurring module along with paypal as I have configured it as per the documentation specified from module's documentation but its still not working.

Any insights on it would be helpful.

Tks,
Vil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through all the configurations, I found out that skipping review order step was causing the problem.Now its working fine.

Tks
-Vil